# Sql Query LIKE not working

Tags: mysql, jsp, jsp-tags

Hi i have trying to do a query, that receives the value on a  querystring, but is not working i think the query it self is no good. could you help me?

So i receive the query on

```
<%String detalhe = request.getParameter("value");%>
```

I wont put connections and stuff, because they work with other querys, so the problem are not the connections.

```
// sql query to retrieve values from the specified table. 

String QueryString = "SELECT * FROM ebooko.dadoslivros WHERE Autor LIKE '%"+detalhe+"%'

OR ano LIKE '%"+detalhe+"%'";;
rs = statement.executeQuery(QueryString);
```

It simply cannot retrive the value, i'm querying.

Adicional info:
Table: dadoslivros
Columns that i need to compare the value: Autor, ano.

for example when i run the Href the value that is passed is: Jules%Verne (i gess it changes SPACES with '%'.

Comment: Nice [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Does the query work, if you use the String `"Jules%Verne"` hardcoded? I could imagine, the `%` is converted to `%25` on the way to your server by your browser.

Comment: Marc since this is a school work and we are just starting to learn this kinds of things that kind of security is not something i'm familiar with, still is good to know that and i will change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`URLDecoder#decode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) to decode the parameters in the query string.

You should also consider using a `PreparedStatement` to prevent [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) attacks.

Comment: I saw the link you gave me but i can't understand it well, still thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it changing the query:

```
String QueryString = "SELECT * FROM dadoslivros WHERE (Data LIKE '%"+detalhe+"%') OR (Autor LIKE '%"+detalhe+"%')";;
```

maybe it can help another person ;)